# How to handle large scale Web Scraping?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

**The Situation:**

I recently started web scraping using selenium and scrapy and i was working on a project where i have a csv file which contains 42 thousand zip codes and my job is to take that zip code and go on this [site](https://www.carecredit.com/doctor-locator/results/Any-Profession/Any-Specialty/00704/?Lat=18.2512&Long=-66.1014&Zip=00704&City=&State=&Profession=&location=00704&Radius=75) input the zip code and scrape all the results.

**The Problem:**

The problem here is that in doing this I have to continuously click the 'load more' button until all the results have been displayed and only once that has finished I can collect the data.

This may not be much of an issue, however it takes 2 minutes to do this per zip code and I have 42 000 to do this with.

**The Code:**

```py
    import scrapy
    from numpy.lib.npyio import load
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException, ElementNotInteractableException, ElementNotSelectableException, NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from items import CareCreditItem
    from datetime import datetime
    import os
    
    
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    global pin_code
    pin_code = input("enter pin code")
    
    class CareCredit1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
        
        name = 'care_credit_1'
        start_urls = ['https://www.carecredit.com/doctor-locator/results/Any-Profession/Any-Specialty//?Sort=D&Radius=75&Page=1']
    
        def start_requests(self):
            
            directory = os.getcwd()
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.headless = True
    
            options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
            path = (directory+r"\\Chromedriver.exe")
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(path,options=options)
    
            #URL of the website
            url = "https://www.carecredit.com/doctor-locator/results/Any-Profession/Any-Specialty/" +pin_code + "/?Sort=D&Radius=75&Page=1"
            driver.maximize_window()
            #opening link in the browser
            driver.get(url)
            driver.implicitly_wait(200)
            
            try:
                cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
                cookies.click()
            except:
                pass
    
            i = 0
            loadMoreButtonExists = True
            while loadMoreButtonExists:
                try:
                    load_more =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="next-page"]')
                    load_more.click()    
                    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
                except ElementNotInteractableException:
                    loadMoreButtonExists = False
                except ElementClickInterceptedException:
                    pass
                except StaleElementReferenceException:
                    pass
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    loadMoreButtonExists = False
    
            try:
                previous_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="previous-page"]')
                previous_page.click()
            except:
                pass
    
            name = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('dl-result-item')
            r = 1
            temp_list=[]
            j = 0
            for element in name:
                link = element.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
                c = link.get_property('href')
                yield scrapy.Request(c)
    
        def parse(self, response):
            item = CareCreditItem()
            item['Practise_name'] = response.css('h1 ::text').get()
            item['address'] = response.css('.google-maps-external ::text').get()
            item['phone_no'] = response.css('.dl-detail-phone ::text').get()
            yield item
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    dt = now.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
    file_name = dt_string+"_"+dt+"zip-code"+pin_code+".csv"
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
        'FEED_URI' : file_name,
        'FEED_FORMAT':'csv'
    })
    process.crawl(CareCredit1Spider)
    process.start()
    print("CSV File is Ready")
```

**items.py**

```py
    import scrapy

    class CareCreditItem(scrapy.Item):
        # define the fields for your item here like:
        # name = scrapy.Field()
        Practise_name = scrapy.Field()
        address = scrapy.Field()
        phone_no = scrapy.Field()
```

**The Question:**

Essentially my question is simple. Is there a way to optimize this code in order for it to perform faster? Or what are the other potential methods in order to handle scraping this data without it taking forever?

Comment: are you using any other external resources? as what you could do is using for example ec2 instances from aws distribute the seedlist over these instances or even potentially spot instances to run the scraper in parallel scraping many zip codes at the same time

Comment: thanks for replying @Kwsswart but i dont really understand what you are saying can you explain it a little or give me some refrence link to understand/

Comment: Essentially if you separate the zipcodes (The seedlist) into many separate seedlists and develop a solution to run the same spider but using different seedlists un many different machines( [aws instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) is an example) then you can essentially have many machines craping at the same time using difference parts of the original seedlist

Comment: Ohh yeah that's a good way to do this problem thanks a lot for your help , also are there other ways to do large scale scraping like without deployment?

Comment: There are many large scale methods particularly in AWS using Lambda or ec2 etc. however if you only want to use a single machine you can look into multithreading(using all the processors in said pc to simultaneously run a program.) or else look into running it continuously (although slowly) on a single process. you can also try running it simply with requests which may speed it up but with a massive amount of seeds it usually is faster to develop a process running in parallel

Comment: Ohh yeah thats a more good way thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: No problem Posted the entire comments made into an answer so that you have it all in one place along with some useful URLS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the site loads the data dynamically from an [api](https://www.carecredit.com/sites/ContentServer?d=&pagename=CCGetLocatorService&Zip=00704&City=&State=&Lat=18.2512&Long=-66.1014&Sort=D&Radius=75&PracticePhone=&Profession=&location=00704&Page=1) you can retrieve the data directly from the api. This will speed things up quite a bit, but I'd still implement a wait to avoid hitting the rate limit.

```
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd

zipcode = '00704'
radius = 75
url = f'https://www.carecredit.com/sites/ContentServer?d=&pagename=CCGetLocatorService&Zip={zipcode}&City=&State=&Lat=&Long=&Sort=D&Radius={radius}&PracticePhone=&Profession=&location={zipcode}&Page=1'
req = requests.get(url)
r = req.json()
data = r['results']

for i in range(2,r['maxPage']+1):
    url = f'https://www.carecredit.com/sites/ContentServer?d=&pagename=CCGetLocatorService&Zip={zipcode}&City=&State=&Lat=&Long=&Sort=D&Radius={radius}&PracticePhone=&Profession=&location={zipcode}&Page={i}'
    req = requests.get(url)
    r = req.json()
    data.extend(r['results'])
    time.sleep(1)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(f'{pd.Timestamp.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y_%H-%M-%S")}zip-code{zipcode}.csv')
```

Comment: thanks for replying i tried to run your code and i got this error :- json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 6 column 2 (char 11)

Comment: @Samyakjain made some small changes, should run without errors now

Comment: thanks a lot @RJ Adriaansen after making a few changes your code is working perfectly now but can you explain in a summary there are somethings which i didnt get but this code is great thanks again  i tried to find the json file from inspect element but i wasnt able to find it there.

Comment: You can find the api link by checking [network activity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) when loading the page. In the json data the `maxPage` key indicates the number of pages. I first retrieved the first page, saved the `results` key as `data`, then looped the other pages and added new results to `data`. Finally save the list of lists to csv with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways in which you can do this.

**1. Creating a distributed system in which you run the spider through multiple machines in order to run in parallel.**

This in my opinio is the better of the options as you can also create a scalable dynamic solution that you will be able to use many times over.

There are many ways of doing this normally it will consist of dividing the seedlist (The Zip Codes) into many separate seedlists in order to have the separate processes working with seperate seedlists, thus the downloads will run in parallel so for example if its on 2 machines it will go 2 times faster, but if on 10 machines its 10 times faster, etc.

In order to do this I might suggest looking into AWS, namely [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) , [AWS EC2 Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) or even [AWS Spot Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/?cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.startDateTime&cards.sort-order=asc) these are the ones I have worked wiht previously and they are not terribly hard to work with.

**2. Alternatively, if you are wanting to run it on a single machine you can take a look into [Multithreading with Python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm), which can help you run the process in parallel on the singular machine.**

**3. This is another option particularly if it is a once off process. You can try running it simply with requests which may speed it up but with a massive amount of seeds it usually is faster to develop a process running in parallel.**

Comment: How would you deal with rate limiting in these approaches?